# Can I apply a different license without reinstalling the server?

Tags: sql-server, license

I have downloaded a trial version of SQL Server 2017. After installation I got this:

> Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Evaluation (64-bit)

I want to buy a license for Standard edition after some time. Can I use the same SQL Server instance and apply the new license to it without any downtime, upgrade/downgrade, or re-install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the SQL Server installer to perform an [Edition Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16).  It doesn't actually re-install the instance; it just applies the product activation key for the new edition.

Comment: so you mean i can run installer again with evaluation version installed, and it will only apply license? no data loss? no re-install of SQL server? everything will remian same?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I mean.

Comment: Relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2017?view=sql-server-ver16#-edition-upgrade You cannot upgrade from Eval to Express, and once upgraded cannot be downgraded to a lower edition (unless it's from Developer). But OP says it's from Eval to Std so that's OK.